# Alias inner join leads to invalid column name

Tags: sql-server, inner-join, alias

I'm trying to INNER JOIN three tables and get it to return values for XML file, but the values that are from second or third table are returned as

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure PROC_Generate_XML_AdForm, Line
>   18 Invalid column name 'VPrSKzNazev'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure PROC_Generate_XML_AdForm, Line
>   20 Invalid column name 'VPrURLCZ1'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure PROC_Generate_XML_AdForm, Line
>   22 Invalid column name 'VPrSlevaCZ1'.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT @xmlVar = (
    SELECT t1.IDS AS 'product_id'
        ,t1.VPrSKzNazev AS 'product_name'
        ,t1.VPrPodkolekce AS 'product_category_id'
        ,'http://www.foo.com/' + t1.VPrURLCZ1 AS 'product_deeplink'
        ,'http://www.foo.com/media-photo/' + t1.IDS + '/370/370.jpg' AS 'product_image'
        ,CAST(ROUND((100 - t1.ProdejDPH) / 100 * t1.VPrSlevaCZ1, 0) AS INT) AS 'product_price'
    FROM SKz AS t1
    INNER JOIN VTbProdDalsi
        ON t1.IDS = VTbProdDalsi.VPrSKzIDS
    INNER JOIN VTbProdDalsi2
        ON t1.IDS = VTbProdDalsi2.VPrSKzIDS
    WHERE t1.VPrIsMain = 1
        AND (
            (
                SELECT SUM(SKz.StavZ - SKz.ObjedP)
                FROM SKz
                WHERE IDS = t1.IDS
                ) > 0
            OR (
                SELECT SUM(ISNULL(SKz.VPrDodPocet, 0) - SKz.ObjedP)
                FROM SKz
                WHERE IDS = t1.IDS
                ) > 0
            )
    FOR XML PATH('product')
        ,ROOT('products')
    )
```

I get the idea that it's probably answered somewhere already, but since I'm new to SQL, I'm not sure how to adapt the answers.

I'm on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SQL Server 2008 R2).

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: What is the stucture of table `SKz`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The solution was not to use the joined table t1 for variables that were not in the SKz table.

```
    select @xmlVar =
    (
    select 
            t1.IDS as 'product_id',
      VTbProdDalsi.VPrSKzNazev as 'product_name',
      t1.VPrPodkolekce as 'product_category_id',
      'http://www.ringit.cz/' + VTbProdDalsi2.VPrURLCZ1 as 'product_deeplink',
      'http://www.ringit.cz/media-photo/' + t1.IDS + '/370/370.jpg' as 'product_image',
      CAST(ROUND(t1.ProdejDPH - t1.ProdejDPH * VTbProdDalsi.VPrSlevaCZ1/100, 0) AS int) as 'product_price'

    from SKz as t1
      inner join VTbProdDalsi on t1.IDS = VTbProdDalsi.VPrSKzIDS 
        inner join VTbProdDalsi2 on t1.IDS = VTbProdDalsi2.VPrSKzIDS
      where t1.VPrIsMain = 1 AND t1.VPrGledis = 1 AND
      ((SELECT SUM(SKz.StavZ - SKz.ObjedP) FROM SKz WHERE IDS = t1.IDS) > 0 OR (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(SKz.VPrDodPocet, 0) - SKz.ObjedP) FROM SKz WHERE IDS = t1.IDS) > 0)
  FOR XML PATH ('product'), ROOT ('products') 
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your problem is residing right here:

```
,t1.VPrSKzNazev AS 'product_name'
        ,t1.VPrPodkolekce AS 'product_category_id'
        ,'http://www.foo.com/' + t1.VPrURLCZ1 AS 'product_deeplink'
```

I would make sure those names match up with what is in table Skz.
Also, if you can't figure it out, can you give us a list of columns from Skz?

Comment: The columns that get error are not in SKz. I would expect they get pulled from the joined table t1.

Here is the list of columns:
ColName
ID
UsrOrder
Sel
RelSkTyp
RefSklad
RefStruct
RefSkSkup
RelDPHn
RelDPHp
RelSkDruh
Obrat
Odbyt
SvazanaZas
RelSKzVC
AUcet
Vynos
Naklad
IDS
EAN
Nazev
Nazev1
Nazev2
SText
SText1
SText2
MJ
MJ2
MJ3
MJ2Koef
MJ3Koef
StavZ
MinLim
MinMax
Hmotnost
Objem
NazevRP
RefSkEURO
Rezer
ObjedP
ObjedV
Reklam
NakupC
NakupDPH
NakupCM
CMKodNC
VNakup
ProdejKc
ProdejDPH
ProdejCM
CMKodPC
ObjMn
ObjNazev
RefAD
Firma
PLU
IObchod
Obrazek
Popis
Popis2

+ few others that are not relevant.